# Win32 multi-level popup menu

Tags: c++, winapi, popupmenu

I'm trying to create a multi-level pop-up menu using win32 and the following code:

```
HMENU CreateSubmenu(HMENU parentMenu, int index)
{
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    wchar_t buffer[256];
    wsprintfW(buffer, L"%d", index);
    AppendMenuW(parentMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, buffer);
    return hSubMenu;
}

void AddMenus(HWND hwnd)
{
    HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = hMenu;

    AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_NEW, L"&New");

    for (int index = 1; index <= 20; ++index)
    {
        hSubMenu = CreateSubmenu(hSubMenu, index);
    }

    AppendMenuW(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_IMPORT_MAIL, L"Import &mail");

    AppendMenuW(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenu, L"&File");
    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
}
```

The menu is created perfectly. But I have a problem with choosing the last element - it is not highlighted (when the mouse is hovered), and it is not available for a click (the pop-up window just disappears). This problem does not occur when there are fewer sub-menu levels in the menu.

Is there some known limitation to win32 api, or do I need to do something else to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: 20 levels of sub-menus seems a little unwieldy.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree, but I can give you a real case - if you want to build a popup folder tree (I know this is not the best decision), which has a multi-level structure.

Comment: According to Raymond in 2003 the [nested menu limit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031230-00/?p=41273) was 25. It may have changed though.

Comment: Oh, I see. @JonathanPotter, thank you for link!

Comment: @KaminskiyGleb once upon a time, the Windows Start menu was an ugly mess of nested pop-ups for a folder tree. Then MS changed it into the single level dynamic beast it is today. Nested pop-up folder trees are definitely not nice for the user to deal with, especially at 20+ levels deep

Comment: @RemyLebeau but the start menu did not use HMENU submenus on Win98+/IE4+, it is a custom draw toolbar IIRC.